# Post/Share status in LinkedIn

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I'm trying to share some content in LinkedIn. I'm getting the user profile, but I can't share a post using this code:

```
[self.client GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,picture-url,email-address,first-name,last-name,headline,location,industry,positions,educations)?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *result) {

        NSLog(@"current user %@", result);

        [self.client POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares/?comment=test&title=commentTest&oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json",accessToken] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *result) {
            NSLog(@"result share %@",result);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"failed to post %@", error);
        }];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"failed to fetch current user %@", error);
    }];
```

I've read this documentation article https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/writing-linkedin-apis, but the thing that I'm not understanding is that do they mean that we post in the request a whole json or xml?? If so, do you have a solution for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding *Content-Type* and *Accept* to the http header.

```
AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
self.client.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
```